Get list of options that have multiple sub options
I've bee trying everything I can, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this. I have a microsoft teams auto attendant and this has multiple Menu Options assigned.    I can load the menu options for the main number, but some of the menu options have their own call flow menu options, which in turn have their own menu options.
Something like this is how it is laid out:
    Main number:
      0 - Operator
      1 - Department A:
        0 - Operator
        1 - Group A1
        2 - Group A2
        3 - Department B:
          0 - Operator
          1 - Group B1
          2 - Group B2
          3 - Department C:
            0 - Operator
            1 - Group C1
            * - Repeat Menu
            # - Previous Menu
          * - Repeat Menu
          # - Previous Menu
       * - Repeat Menu
       # - Previous Menu
    2 - Department D
    3 - Department E
    * - Repeat Menu
    # - Previous Menu

Of course, the real data has many more nested menus.  Each menu can have a maximum of 12 options, 0-9 wit * and #.  Without knowing how deep these menus go, is there a way to iterate through the options and sub options?
The following code is what I have to get the main call flow options, I just can't figure out a way to take each option and expand the sub menu options without knowing the total number of child levels.
function addMenuOption {
    param(
        [string]$Key,
        [string]$Action,
        [string]$VoiceResponse,
        [string]$callTarget,
        [string]$ID,
        [string]$autoAttendant
    )
    process {
        if ($Action -eq "TransferCallToOperator") {
            $Key = 0
            $VoiceResponse = "Operator"
            $callTarget = "Operator"
            $ID = "Operator"
        }

        $newMenuOption = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Key = $Key
            Action = $Action
            VoiceResponses = $VoiceResponses
            CallTarget = $callTarget
            ID = $ID
            AutoAttendant = $autoAttendant
        }
        return $newMenuOption
    }
}

$allAttendants = Get-CsAutoAttendant

$callTree=@()
$rootAttendant = $allAttendants | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*AA Georgian Top*"}

$menuOptions = @()


#$parent = $autoAttendant.Name
$rootAttendant.DefaultCallFlow.Menu.MenuOptions | ForEach-Object {
    $AutoAttendant = $rootAttendant.Name
    $targetID = $_.CallTarget.Id
    $CallTarget = ($allAttendants | Where-Object {$_.ApplicationInstances -eq $targetID} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) 
    $newOption = addMenuOption -key ($_.DtmfResponse).ToString().Substring(4) -Action ($_.Action) -VoiceResponses ($_.VoiceResponses) -callTarget $CallTarget -ID ($targetID) -autoAttendant $AutoAttendant
    $menuOptions += $newOption
}
$callTree += $menuOptions
$callTree | ft

Ideally if the CallTarget and the AutoAttendant are the same, the script would not attempt to look for a child menu.  For the CallTargets that are unique, I am trying to iterate through each one and then iterate through each of the subsequent menus.

I would recommend using a class where $option is an array of Menu and $submenu is the submenu.
class Menu {
   [Menu[]] $options
   [Menu] $submenu
}

